# Unable to use text taken from textbox in Window 1 to be used in Window 2

Tags: c#, wpf

I've already make object of window1

```
MainWindow win1_obj = new MainWindow();
```

used it to access the variables in window1 that are `Public`

```
public int banks, banks_size, timer_time, threshold;
```

used onClick event to assign them values from textboxes in window1

```
 if (checkbox_enable_banks.IsChecked == true)
        {
            banks = int.Parse(txtbox_banks_numbers.Text);
        }
        if(checkbox_enable_size.IsChecked==true)
        {
            banks_size = int.Parse(txtbox_bank_size.Text);
        }
        if (checkbox_enable_time.IsChecked == true)
        {
            timer_time = int.Parse(txtbox_timer_time.Text);
        }
        if (checkbox_enable_threshold.IsChecked == true)
        {
            threshold = int.Parse(txtbox_power_threshold.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            threshold = 20;
        }
```

but when accessing them with them with `win1_obj`in window2 as with the following method

```
if (win1_obj.timer_time > 0)
        {
            seconds = win1_obj.timer_time;

        }
```

and

```
label_threshold.Content = win1_obj.threshold +"%";
```

it just don't do anything, neither it assigns `timer_time` to `seconds` nor `threshold` vlue to `label_threshold.Content`

Comment: Does it get to the line in the debugger if you put a breakpoint there?

Comment: What is `win1_obj` in window2?  Your implication is it's not the same object, which would explain why none of the values are being used.

Comment: When you call `MainWindow win1_obj = new MainWindow();` within the code, you create a new instance of `MainWindow`, and depending on the placement of this line, it is possible that this instance is different than what you see on the screen.

Comment: `win1_obj` is the `object` for Window1 created in Window2 to access variables in window1 @Charles

Comment: @Ghani that won't work.  You've created a *new* instance of `MainWindow`, which isn't the instance you've clicked a button on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must be giving values to properties in `MainWindow`  put you are tying to access the values in `window2` by instance of `MainWindow`  means by

```
MainWindow win1_obj = new MainWindow();
```

keep in mind that `new` creats a instance of object means new memory location will be assign to that particular object. If you want to access the properties simply give add `static` like `public static int banks;` create a class and give static properties.

```
public class WindowClass
{
   public static int banks; 
    //and other properties 

}
```

and you can get and set the value directly with class name and property e.g

```
WindowClass.banks
```